# ORA-01017 Invalid Username/Password when creating a 12c database

Tags: oracle12c, ora-01017, dbca

I've started learning Oracle 12C but I keep getting a ORA-01017 error each time I try to create a database. I want to find out what I'm doing wrong but since the DBCA closes and the database isn't fully created I have no idea where I can look the parameters that generated the error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

DBCA creates a log file when creating a database. This log is created under $ORACLE_BASE/cfgtoollogs/dbca/.

You can also debug it by generating the database creation scripts instead of actually creating it. See here for example:
http://www.realmagicdba.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/2014-07-30-11_57_58-database-configuration-assistant-create-database-step-12-of-16.png

also, I've created step by step for creating a Oracle 12c database using dbca - so you might find that useful as well:
https://www.realdbamagic.com/installing-oracle-12-1-0-2-part-2/